# Сервис для получения событий от бэкэнда об изменениях данных на сервере в реальном времени

Tags: веб-программирование, amazon, amazon-web-services

Я пишу веб приложение в связке с AWS сервисами на бэкэнде. Приложение должно в реальном времени актуализировать отображаемые данные, если они изменяются на сервере. Например, в приложении есть список комментариев, если кто-нибудь добавит комментарий, то все пользователи приложения должны сразу же увидеть изменения. Подскажите пожалуйста какой-нибудь сервис для этого, желательно Амазоновский. Похоже мне подходит сервис [AWS Kinesis](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/kinesis/), но я не могу найти примеров, как получать события об изменении данных

Comment: Может быть вам подойдут websockets или long polling на node.js?

Comment: это подошло бы, но я ищу готовый сервис, который бы выдерживал большие нагрузки. У меня сейчас весь бэкэнд на амазоновских сервисах, хотелось бы и здесь использовать амазон